# Rigid filiform Lie algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In https://mathoverflow.net/q/126795, @Dietrich Burde says that He had read in the literature about rigid Lie algebras that no filiform Lie algebra can be rigid in $\mathcal{L}_n(\mathbb{C})$ (He could not verify such affirmation, and did not find a valid proof).

Someone knows which is (are) the paper(s) where I can read such affirmation?
Is there any significant advance on this interesting subject over the last ten years?

Answer (score 0):

The literature I have mentioned in my [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67817/rigid-nilpotent-lie-algebras/126795#126795) is the following:

J. M. Ancochea-Bermudez, J. R. Gómez-Martin, G. Valeiras,
M. Goze: *Sur les composantes irreductibles de la variete des lois
d'algebres de Lie nilpotentes*. J. Pure Appl. Algebra **106**, No.1 (1996), 11-22.

In this article it is claimed without proof that no filiform Lie algebra in $\mathcal{L}_n(\mathbb{C})$ can be rigid.

Rigid Lie algebras are still studied intensively (by myself, and many other people like Paulo Tirao and his student Joan Felipe Herrera-Granada). You will find many articles if you search on rigid Lie algebras.